# How do I let a method take an indeterminate number of Lists of varying types?

Tags: c#, .net, list

How can I define a method that takes an indeterminate number of single-dimension Lists of varying types and then iterates through them? I am trying the following, but the params argument gets an error: "Unexpected use of an unbound generic type".

```
private void doStuffWithLists(params List<>[] lists)
{
    foreach (var list in lists)
    {
        // do type-specific stuff with each list
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the open generic type `List<>` is only useful for *very* limited reflection scenarios (for example, constructing a *specific* list type at runtime, like `MakeGenericType()`). You can't use it as a placeholder for `List<T>` - or `List<SomeSpecificType>` - they work differently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They would have to be non-generic lists if the types are not guaranteed to be common. So:

```
private void doStuffWithLists(params IList[] lists)
{
    foreach (var list in lists)
    {
        // do type-specific stuff with each list
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I've tried this, but the compiler complains that `IList` "requires 1 type arguments". If I try with just `List`, the method compiles but my calling code gets errors when converting, for example, List<MyClass> to List.

Comment: @NSouth you're missing a `using` directive; add `using System.Collections;` to the top of your file - then `IList` should work fine

Comment: Maybe, using the other *ancestor*, something like `private void doStuffWithLists<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists)`. You can then have, for example, `foreach (var list in lists) { int count = list.Count(); }` etc..

Comment: @MarcGravell, that was it! Thank you so much. The method is now working as desired.